# TypeError: tagIds.join is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I am getting this error in javascript.

```
TypeError: tagIds.join is not a function
```

I am trying to join many tags id together and delete them at once, so here I used tagsId to join the tags and separator them with commas. in the console, it is working well when I tested it. but in my code, it doesn't work. here is the code.

```
const deleteTags = async (postId, tagIds) => {
  const joinedTags = tagIds.join(",");
  joinedTags = await db.sequelize.query(
    `delete from posttags where postId = ${postId} and tagId in (${joinedTags});`,
    { type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.destroy }
  );
  console.log("joinedTags", joinedTags);
  res.json({ joinedTagsResults });
};
```

this is the error as well.

```
   const joinedTags = tagIds.join(",");
                              ^
   TypeError: tagIds.join is not a function
```

if I am doing something wrong please let me know.

thanks

Comment: What are you passing in as `tagIds`?

Comment: Tags id, as an argument.

Comment: Yes, I see that.  If you put `console.log(tagIds)`, what does it display?

Comment: it just consoles out the tag id.
my tagIds 315 the result of the conosle.

Comment: `join` is used on arrays, not strings.

Comment: could you please make it a bit clear because I am a bit new in js:)

Comment: you need share `deleteTags( ... ) function call code `, now, `tagIds` is not array

Comment: @MERN thanks for answering. yes I am a bit confused about how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
const deleteTags = async (postId, tagIds) => {
    let joinedTags = tagIds;

    // if tagIds is array
    if (Array.isArray(tagIds)) joinedTags = tagIds.join(',');
    ...
};

const postId = 5;

deleteTags(postId, [315, 312]);
deleteTags(postId, "315"); // Now, this also working
```

Comment: Thanks,  man it just solved the error.:)))))